# CMake: use of true/false or on/off or yes/no in generator expressions

Tags: cmake

**Is there any way to make it easy or possible to use `true/false` or `on/off` or `yes/no` in CMake's generator expressions, besides `1/0`?**

## Context

As far as [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) is concerned, only `1` and `0` are recognized within generator expressions.

However, as far as the [if](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/if.html) command is concerned, `1`, `ON`, `YES`, `TRUE`, `Y` are all considered boolean values.

This makes some things confusing; for example, one could use the `option` command to get an input from the user in the configuration phase, and then try to use its value within a generator expression; however, in this case, cmake would complain if the value is not `1` or `0`. The same applies to boolean variables stored in CMake's cache.

## [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) Example

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)

add_custom_target(print
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo $<1:hello> $<0:world>
    )
```

Create a `CMakeLists.txt` file with the above content, run `cmake .` and then `make` (generator expressions are only evaluated at build time). It will print `hello`, as expected.

However, the following example won't even work with the `cmake` command itself:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)

add_custom_target(print2
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo $<true:hello> $<false:world>
    )
```

Here's its output (at configuration time):

```
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (add_custom_target):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<true:hello>

  Expression did not evaluate to a known generator expression


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (add_custom_target):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<false:world>

  Expression did not evaluate to a known generator expression


-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/cmake
```

Again:

**Is there any way to make it easy or possible to use `true/false` or `on/off` or `yes/no` in CMake's generator expressions, besides `1/0`?**

Or, alternatively, an easy way to convert a variable with one of these values to `1/0` so it could then be used in generator expressions?

Comment: You could write a function which evaluates your variable with an `if` and set the value of the variable in the parent scope to 1 or 0 accordingly. Not nice, I have to confess.

Comment: Yes, this is the first thing that comes to mind. I might end up doing that or simply using `if/else`, instead of generator expressions. I will wait to see if someone comes with a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is what the `$<BOOL:...>` generator expression is for. See the start of the [Logical Expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#logical-expressions) section of the generator expression docs. Modifying your example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)

add_custom_target(print2
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo $<$<BOOL:true>:hello> $<$<BOOL:false>:world>
)
```

Comment: Did you test this? `if($<BOOL:true>)
    message("$<BOOL:true accepted by if")
else()
    message("$<BOOL:true not accepted by if")
endif()
message(" $ <BOOL:true>: " $<BOOL:true>)` is not working for me in CMake 3.17

Comment: Generator expressions are only evaluated at generation time, not at configure time. The `message()` command is not able to evaluate them because it tries to do that at configure time. That's why it isn't documented as supporting generator expressions. The example given uses `add_custom_command()`, which does support generator expressions. They are evaluated at generation time when CMake writes the command into the project file (build.ninja, Makefile, Visual Studio project file, etc.).